# Share Internet Connection via Ethernet connected Router over the LAN

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, usb-modem, lan

I have a USB modem that works perfectly with Ubuntu but doesn't work with my Wifi router.

I want a set-up where the USB modem is connected to my PC and my PC is connected to my Router (via ethernet) and I can **share/forward the net connection via the Router** to other appliances. (Basically, a workaround for my modem not being supported by the Router).

- Router: TP-Link TL-MR3220
- Ubuntu version: 14.04
- Modem: ZTE AC 8700 EVDO
- ISP: BSNL EVDO

Additional Info:

I've tried doing Internet Connection Sharing on Windows 7 but it didn't work. Couldn't figure out how to do this in Ubuntu either.

Similar question that didn't help me: [How do I share my Ubuntu's Internet connection with a LAN (via hardware router)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49627/how-do-i-share-my-ubuntus-internet-connection-with-a-lan-via-hardware-router)

Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Did you plug the network cable into the WAN port (blue) of the router? Did you configure the router to use DHCP client mode for its WAN connection (using "Static IP" mode isn't a good idea in this case)? Did you make sure your system didn't automatically select the "Wired network connection" created by default but the wired connection that you had created?

Comment: I plugged it into WAN port: No response. Router didn't detect a connection. Perhaps I didn't configure it properly on the PC.

I also ensured that my connection has been selected. Sorry I am a newbie in networking and unfamiliar with most terms. Trying to get the hang of it all.

Comment: I have this checkbox in WAN settings: "Get IP with Unicast DHCP (It is usually not required.)" which is unchecked. Also, DHCP server is enabled with default gateway as 192.168.0.1(Router's web UI address too).

Comment: The thing is your router should act as a DHCP *server* on LAN but as an DHCP *client* on WAN  otherwise it won't work. Also you can try hooking up some other device with your computer and see if it is able to make a connection.

Comment: Okay. Understanding it a bit now. But how to implement this? I assume I don't need to alter the existing DHCP server settings. So, how to make it act as client on WAN? Adding a screenshot of my WAN settings in the question above.

Comment: @aero31aero, did you find a way to make it work?. If so would be interested to hear how you did .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Connect & Share your Internet Connection (Wired & Wireless)](http://askubuntu.com/q/171914/65926)

Comment: I have the exact same question and I am looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- install dhcp server on Ubuntu version: 14.04
- share internet connection on Ubuntu version: 14.04
- restart Ubuntu version: 14.04
- reset your TP-Link TL-MR3220
- turn off dhcp of TP-Link TL-MR3220 or enable it to client mode
- turn off firewall of TP-Link TL-MR3220
- restart TP-Link TL-MR3220
- its done

......if you don't know how to install dhcp server on Ubuntu version: 14.04 click on link http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-dhcp-server-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: You should at least précis the essential steps in any link you rely on to answer a question. In time, the link may become unavailable rendering your answer useless.

Comment: Stupid me, commenting so late. But anyway, even if the link doesn't work, the user can easily Google "dhcp server linux".

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here:

networking - How to use a 4G phone to provide WAN/Internet service to a LAN? - Ask Ubuntu
[How to use a 4G phone to provide WAN/Internet service to a LAN?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666972/how-to-use-a-4g-phone-to-provide-wan-internet-service-to-a-lan/666987#666987)