# Sharing internet from USB-Modem to an external router via ethernet cable

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, usb-modem, router

My Ubuntu 16.04 system is connected to the Internet by means of a USB-Modem.

How do I share this internet to an external router(Netgear) through the ethernet cable connected to my computer?

- I've done the first step of going to settings and sharing the Wired
  Network(USB) in IPv4 settings.
- I've connected the ethernet cable attached to my PC to the Internet port(blue-colored port) of my router, not the local ports.

Now, how do I configure the router to begin with, when the Ethernet connection is not getting connected at all?
The system continuously tries to connect to it but fails.

**Update:**

I've assigned an IP to my ethernet connection and it connects to the system.

Now, how do I configure my router so that I could share the internet?
Do I use a static IP and set the IP of my ethernet connection as the gateway or the IP of my USB-modem connection?

Comment: Well you'll have to NAT the connection at you PC so there's little point for router to NAT it again so you can plug your PC in the router's switch port (essentially just using it as a switch) but would need a static IP for your PC and tell router to hand out your IP as gateway in its DHCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing to connect because when you use Ubuntu's sharing mode, it **doesn't** set up a DHCP server.

You need to manually assign an IP address to the device connected to the Ubuntu system.

Comment: I'm able to connect to the wired ethernet network after manually assigning an IP. We're halfway there now. 

How do I configure my router now? Do I use a static IP configuration and set the IP of my ethernet connection as the gateway?

Comment: @GirishShankar - That should work - just make sure that you don't give it an IP that conflicts with another...

Comment: @AndroidDev- I had followed the instructions given in the link below.  
Yet, I'm not able to get internet access through my router. Please help. 


http://askubuntu.com/questions/49627/how-do-i-share-my-ubuntus-internet-connection-with-a-lan-via-hardware-router/50010#50010