# Sharing Internet from Wifi via Ethernet to a Wifi repeater

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, dhcp, connection-sharing

Similar kind of Question has been asked and answered but my problem is a little different. I live in a building where to get Wifi, you need to buy a voucher which works on a single device for a month by storing that device's MAC address. I have bought the voucher for my Laptop and want to share the internet to a Wifi repeater via Ethernet so the rest of my devices can use the internet too. The Wifi repeater is **TP Link TL-WA850RE 7.0**. It does has a single LAN port and i have put it in Access Point mode. My **Ubantu version is 22.04LTS**. I have followed this [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49627/how-do-i-share-my-ubuntus-internet-connection-with-a-lan-via-hardware-router) yet this still doesn't help me.

- I first made a new Wired connection, named it "My Network", went into
  its IPV4 settings and selected "shared to other computers".

1. Next i opened the Web Gui of my Wifi Repeater, selected "use the
   following IP address" and put following in the form;
2. Ip address :10.42.0.2
3. Subnet Mask :255.255.255.0
4. Default Gateway : 10.42.0.1, (which is the IPV4 address of the                shared Ethernet connection i made)
5. Primary DNS :10.10.0.1, (which is the DNS of my Wifi connection) and secondary DNS :8.8.8.8
6. Next i changed the DHCP Server settings of Wifi Repeater to Auto (turning them to OFF does nothing). Yet i am still not getting any internet access on the Repeater.

I just dual booted into Ubantu because i was having the same problem in Windows. It does work in Windows but only if i use **Connectify Pro** application's wired router mode, so i do know that my Wifi Repeater can share the internet.I don't want to use any application and thus installed Ubantu but getting the same problem here. What am i doing Wrong? Pictures are attached. [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaTNt.png) [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pQTr.png)
[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI4gK.png)

Comment: So basically you shared your wireless connection to Ethernet, connected an access point and turned on DHCP server on the access point? I think the problem may be that DHCP server on your AP isn't sending the correct default gateway to clients. Wireless clients of the AP must know too that the default gateway is 10.42.0.1, it is not enough that the AP itself knows this. Check the address settings your wireless clients are getting from the AP.

Comment: If i turn on DHCP server on AP, i need to configure it and so i do put the default gateway to 10.42.0.1 which can also be seen on my connected wireless clients. If i put the DHCP server of AP to off, the Gateway remains the same i.e 10.42.0.1 as can be seen on the connected wireless clients.

Comment: Also, if i put primary DNS to 10.42.0.1 in Ip configuration form on Tp link Web Gui, the 'Globe' art says "internet connected" on the Network Map page of TP LINK WEB GUI, yet wireless connected clients still can't access internet. If i change the primary DNS to 10.10.0.1 which is the Primary DNS of connected WIFI on Laptop, the 'Globe' says "internet disconnected"

Comment: Don't bother with DNS at first. Try to make it work using IP addresses only. I guess something's still wrong with routing setup. That needs to be investigated thoroughly. Once evereything works at IP address level, adding correct DNS is a next step and should be fairly easy.

Comment: I would also first check if your Internet connection sharing is working properly. Connect another computer via Ethernet instead of TP-LINK, give it the same IP address & other parameters as you gave to TP-LINK and check if it can access the Internet (again, first using IP addresses, don't bother with DNS). If not, then there's a problem with your Internet connection sharing. If yes, the problem is in TP-LINK.